# XML node comparison

Tags: c#

XML #1:

```
<row>
  <USER_ID>2</USER_ID>
  <USER_NAME>OOP</USER_NAME>
  <EMAIL>example@gmail.com</EMAIL>
  <PASSWORD>7515464</PASSWORD>
  <USER_TYPE>3</USER_TYPE>
</row>
<row>
  <USER_ID>3</USER_ID>
  <USER_NAME>OOP</USER_NAME>
  <EMAIL>example@gmail.com</EMAIL>
  <PASSWORD>7515464</PASSWORD>
  <USER_TYPE>3</USER_TYPE>
</row>
```

XML #2:

```
<row>
  <USER_ID>4</USER_ID>
  <USER_NAME>OS</USER_NAME>
  <EMAIL>example@gmail.com</EMAIL>
  <PASSWORD>7515464</PASSWORD>
  <USER_TYPE>3</USER_TYPE>
</row>
<row>
  <USER_ID>2</USER_ID>
  <USER_NAME>OS</USER_NAME>
  <EMAIL>example1@gmail.com</EMAIL>
  <PASSWORD>7515464</PASSWORD>
  <USER_TYPE>3</USER_TYPE>
</row>
```

I want the application to split the two stacks in chunks and add random number to each chunk and comparing the corresponding nodes in these sub-stacks by using multiple threads

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: What have you tried to do? You have to write some code in order for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
this class generate random number

using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        // Buffer storage.
        byte[] data = new byte[4];

        // Ten iterations.
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
        // Fill buffer.
        rng.GetBytes(data);

        // Convert to int 32.
        int value = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);
        Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
    }
}
```